# How to make the Dash Button go straight to the Applications menu?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

When I click the Dash Home button on the left bar near the top it opens a window up with the home tab by default, how can i change it to the applications tab by default instead ?.

I'm using 12.04

Comment: To be honest I found that annoying also, but just used the "super/windows key & A" shortcut to go to the applications menu, so I too am interested in a simple answer to this question. :o)

Comment: windows/super key + A works but i rather just have it do that when i click it instead ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- Right-click the Dash Home button and select "Applications" from its quicklist.
- Use the <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut.
- Patch the [lp:unity](https://code.launchpad.net/unity) codebase to open the dash to `unity-lens-applications`.

As of 12.04 LTS, there is no configuration option to change launcher click behavior.

Comment: I think, it would be better, if the list is changed into a bulleted list, instead of a numbered list

Comment: @AnwarShah Okay. You can edit problems on your own, you know. :)

Comment: nah this is not what I'm looking for.
i want it to go to the applications tab when i left click it, please ;)

Comment: @StevenShearing you *can't*. Wait for someone else to do it or learn how to change it.